# Non-hamiltonian Graphs with unique hamiltonian path between exactly 4 pair of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Need some example graphs which are not Hamiltonian, i.e, does not admit any Hamiltonian cycle,  but which have Hamiltonian path. It has Hamiltonian paths between exactly 4 pair of vertices. I have identified one such group of graphs. Would like to see more such examples.[Redundant information deleted; thanks to Sadeq Dousti for pointing it out]

Comment: "All Hamilton-connected graphs are Hamiltonian." (see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hamilton-ConnectedGraph.html). So, you need not say that the graph neither admits any Hamiltonian cycle, nor is Hamiltonian-connected (the latter is redundant).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of the constructions in this answer are from Niel de Beaudrap's answer.

Assume that $H$ is an arbitrary graph with a unique Hamiltonian path between $v_l$ and $v_r$.

#### Construction I.

Assume that $G_l$ is a graph, and $U_l \subseteq V(G_l)$ s.t. there are exactly 2 Hamiltonian paths starting from vertices in $U_l$. Similarly for $G_r$. Attach $G_l$ to $H$ by adding edges between $v_l$ and vertices in $U_l$. Similarly attach $G_r$ to $H$ using $v_r$. The resulting graph has the required property.

#### Construction II.

Assume that there is no other Hamiltonian path in $H$ starting from $v_l$, and that $G$ is a graph, and there are exactly 4 Hamiltonian paths starting from vertices in $U \subseteq V(G)$. Attach $G$ to $H$ by adding edges between the vertices in $U$ and $v_l$. The resulting graph has the required property.

An example for $G$ in the second construction is a $C_{4}$, taking two non-adjacent vertices as $U$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a trivial example class [and now, also generalized slightly in view of Esha's comment]: graphs G(h,k,n) constructed from a path of length n, by adjoining a cycle of length h and a cycle of length k to the two ends. If the two cycles are

> A<sub>1</sub> – P<sub>0</sub> – A<sub>2</sub> – ... – A<sub>h−1</sub> – A<sub>1</sub>

and

> B<sub>1</sub> – P<sub>n</sub> – B<sub>2</sub> – ... – B<sub>k−1</sub> – B<sub>1</sub> ,

connected by the path

> P<sub>0</sub> – P<sub>1</sub> – ... – P<sub>n</sub> ,

then there are Hamiltonian paths between each vertex pair {A<sub>a</sub> , B<sub>b</sub>} for a,b ∈ {1,2} but for no others.

Comment: @Esha: Wow... perhaps you should have waited for a more interesting class of graphs before accepting my answer?

Comment: I think your graph class can be generalized as 2 cycles attached to endpoints of a path.

Comment: Btw,does accepting your answer means I wont get any more intersting replies?

Comment: @Esha: You're right about the cycles: I'll generalize my answer to include this. Also: I would certainly imagine that accepting my answer will have a negative impact on the number of people who look into the question.

Comment: @Esha: if you change your mind, you can change which answer is marked accepted.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235